# Getting data to state component in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am rendering animal named component in the app component and in the animal component i am maping the animal array from the state and sending the data to card component.card componrnt are making cards for every animals.basically like this  App->home>card. now that i have a remove butoon in the card compo i need the bring the card animal name into the app compo once the button is clicked. how i am able to do so ??

how can i bring the animal.name inside the this.removeHandeler so that i can remove the card using the remove button in card component.

```
App component

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { animals, birds } from "./component/Data";
import Navbar from "./component/Navbar";
import Home from "./component/Home";
import Animal from "./component/Animal";
import Bird from "./component/Bird";
import About from "./component/About";
import "./App.css";

export default class App extends Component {
  state = { animals: animals, birds: birds, search: "" };

  removeHandeler = (name) => {
    console.log(name);
    const UpdatedArray = this.state.animals.filter(
      (animal) => animal.name !== name
    );
    this.setState({ animals: UpdatedArray });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route
            path="/animal"
            element={
              <Animal
                animals={this.state.animals}
                removeCard={() => this.removeHandeler(animal.name)}
              />
            }
          />
          <Route path="/bird" element={<Bird birds={this.state.birds} />} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

Animal component

```
import React from "react";
import Card from "./Card";
const animal = ({ animals, removeCard }) => {
  const animalList = animals.map((animal) => {
    return (
      <Card
        name={animal.name}
        likes={animal.likes}
        key={animal.name}
        removeCard={removeCard}
      />
    );
  });

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div>
        <h1> Animal List</h1>
        <input />
      </div>
      <div className="animalList_container "> {animalList} </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default animal;
```

card component

```
import React from "react";

const Card = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <div className="image_wrapper">
        <button className="removeButton" onClick={props.removeCard}>
          X
        </button>
        <img
          src={`https://source.unsplash.com/500x400/?${props.name} `}
          alt={`${props.name} `}
        />{" "}
      </div>
      <div className="animal_info">
        <h2>{props.name[0].toUpperCase() + props.name.slice(1)}</h2>
        <div className="social_wrapper">
          <button onClick={props.removeLikes}> Remove </button>
          <p>{props.likes} &#9829;</p>
          <button onClick={props.addLikes}> Add like </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

Comment: it's missing a lot of code to be able to run. Can you make a working example here: https://codesandbox.io/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Card` component has the name of the animal, so you can just call your `removeHandeler` function from there. Simply pass it in the `Animal` props like this :

```
<Animal
    animals={this.state.animals}
    removeCard={this.removeHandeler.bind(this)}
/>
```

And in the `Card` component, call it in the `onClick`:

```
<button className="removeButton" onClick={() => {props.removeCard(props.name)}}>
```